# Copy files from a SharePoint folder to a AzureBlob folder using microsoft flow

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-blob-storage, power-automate

I have created a flow using predefined template "Copy files from a SharePoint folder to an AzureBlob folder".

When am trying to copy pdf or doc file, flow is working successfully but the copied blob in Azure is empty pdf or doc files(Size 0), while loading same files manually direct in Azure blob storage is working correctly.

Please help me in figuring out the actual issue so that I will able to copy actual files with content in Azure blob storage from SharePoint.

Comment: No one will be able to help you if you don't give us any information other than "not working". That being said, check out this tutorial, maybe it helps: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/copy-files-from-sharepoint-to-an-azure-blob-storage-using-microsoft-flow/

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the "Create file" flow while testing to see the output.  I would guess the issue has to do with your connection to Azure Storage in your flow.  I tested without issue.